# How to add prerequisite check in a googletest test suite?

Tags: googletest

I have a test suite with multiple unit tests, and all these unit tests expect specific working directory as they use relative path to load some test data. If unit test executable is executed from some wrong directory, all these unit tests fail.

What's the proper way to make this check in gtest? Preferably so that I get one single failure message instead of having 50 failed unit tests with the same message.

One way is to use fixture and do single time check, but in that case I still get all these 50 unit test failures instead of skipping the rest of the test suite

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release [v.1.10.0](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.10.0) gtest provides the new **GTEST_SKIP()** macro (hooray!!).

It can be used as follows:

```
TEST(SkipTest, DoesSkip)
{
  if (my_condition_to_skip)
    GTEST_SKIP();

  // ...
}
```

As far as I know, there is no documentation on this yet except for the [unit test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/test/gtest_skip_test.cc) of the feature.

As you can see in the unit test, entire fixtures classes can also be skipped. The skipped tests are marked as not failing with a green color. But you still get one output per test:

```
[----------] 2 tests from Fixture
[ RUN      ] Fixture.DoesSkip
[  SKIPPED ] Fixture.DoesSkip (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] Fixture.DoesSkip2
[  SKIPPED ] Fixture.DoesSkip2 (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from Fixture (12 ms total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Googletest has built-in filtering feature. Provided that all your tests have common part of the name (e.g. they are in single fixture), you can disable them when running tests:

```
./foo_test --gtest_filter=-PathDependentTests.*
```

Or by setting environment variable `GTEST_FILTER` to the same string

[GoogleTest 1.8 docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests)
[Googletest master docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests)

If you still want a failure but only one instead of fifty then it's probably not the best mechanism unfortunately.